# Zoom & Panning (grouping multiple images) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im starting a project that involves more than 1 image to be zoomed via mouse scrolled and then panned within its bordered boundaries. So if the images reaches the far left/right the panning stops.

I have been testing out the panzoom jquery, but i can not get my head around this.

for example, the below is code used for zooming/panning a group conataining 4 images.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #focal { width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="focal">           
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="panzoom">
            <img src="C:\...\blue.jpg" width="20" height="20">
            <img src="C:\...\green.jpg" width="20" height="20">
            <img src="C:\...\blue.jpg" width="20" height="20">
            <img src="C:\...\green.jpg" width="20" height="20">
        </div>     
    </div>
</section>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var $section = $('#focal');          
        var $panzoom = $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom();
        $panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0, {
                increment: 0.1,
                focal: e });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Does anyone know what the code would be to include boundaries. As mentioned above, i would like the panning to stop once its reached its 'borders' on webpage. Also, the code what it would look like as a whole.

Many thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. We invite you to indent your code for readability. I also invite you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help filled with tips about 'how' to format a decent question.